# A class Mercedes 2005 - seems to have power, but doesn't crank

Tags: electrical, starting, mercedes-benz

Turning the electronic key, electrics come on but engine does not turn over. The only sound is the clicking as the key is inserted. I have replaced the batteries in the key.

Comment: Fails to start is a bit broad.  Does the engine turn over?  Do you hear any sound from the engine?

Comment: Off hand it sounds like your battery is low or failing. It can deliver enough power to run the electrics, but not enough to crank the engine. Can you get someone to help you jump the car? If you can get it running (and are in the US) many car parts stores will do a free battery check for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically what happens when you have a low or bad battery. Try jump starting the car. If that works make sure to have the battery tested. Otherwise you might get stranded again